# A question about bilinear maps.

Tags: abstract-algebra

[This wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_map) says:

Let $B:V\times W\to X$, and $(v,w)\in V\times W$. If $v$ in $(v,w)$ remains fixed, then $B$ becomes a linear mapping. I quote **"In other words, if we hold the first entry of the bilinear map fixed, while letting the second entry vary, the result is a linear operator, and similarly if we hold the second entry fixed."**

What does this exactly mean? If $(a,b),(a,c)\in V\times W$, then does this imply $$B((a,b)+(a,c))=B((a,b))+B((a,c))$$

Similarly, if $(m,n),(p,n)\in V\times W$, does this also imply $$B((m,n)+(p,n))=B((m,n))+B((p,n))$$ Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Oh. Thanks anon! The motivation for this question was I was having trouble figuring out why some of the examples of bilinear maps given on the page were bilinear maps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, but I think you want these formulas instead:

$$B(a,b+c)=B(a,b)+B(a,c)\\B(a+b,c)=B(a,c)+B(b,c)$$

Comment: Whoops, my answer was wrong. Jared's is correct. In fact, one can show that if a map is both *linear* on $V^2$ and *bilinear*, it must be the zero map.

Comment: And the reason we want these formulas is: we write the application of linear maps on vectors as $Av$, without parentheses (probably in order to reduce clutter).

Comment: And just an additional question: Is $B(a,\delta (b+c))=\delta B(a,b)+\delta B(a,c)$?

Comment: Yes.  That is correct.